# How to ensure Forms are the top window

Tags: forms, powershell, winforms, window

I have a PS script that implements System.Windows.Forms in order to query technicians for some data.

I create the forms and set both .Topmost and .TopLevel to true in an attempt to have them show up over the Powershell window, but they continue to (for some reason inconsistently) appear behind the Powershell window. This slows down the process and is confusing in its inconsistency.

If anyone knows how to ensure these windows stay top without a mountain of code larger than the script itself that would be incredibly useful. I'll include the code I use to build one of the basic forms below.

Any **simple** solution that will allow these Forms to appear over the Powershell window is appreciated. It could even just minimize the PS window, but I don't want to launch without the window as we need it open. Thanks.

```
$form.Text = 'Computer Name Entry'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(550,400)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,300)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,40)
$label.Text = 'Text is here:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$form.Topmost = $true
$form.TopLevel = $true

$form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    Do-Stuff
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, `$form.Add_Shown({ $textBox.Select() })` should be changed for `$form.Add_Shown({ $this.Activate() })`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. If it is not staying as the topmost window (TopLevel defaults to true anyway, by the way, so it doesn't help setting this) then something is triggering the other Window which is making it the topmost window. As explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413), you can't force something to remain the topmost window.

Comment: You have either `Form.Activate()`, which calls `SetForegroundWindow()`, or `BringToFront()`, which call `SetWindowPos()` with `HWND_TOP` set. Remove `$form.TopLevel = $true` (useless). `.Topmost` may get in the way.

Comment: In addition to the other comments about using `.Activate()`, I can only echo them and add that I have always launched forms with the following code: `[System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost]::EnableModelessKeyboardInterop($form); $form.Show(); $form.Activate()`

Comment: @Ash, the problem is _intermittent_, and therefore not easy to reproduce. The [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.enablemodelesskeyboardinterop?view=net-5.0) you reference seems to be for WPF / WinForms _interop_ and only accepts a _WPF_ window as its argument.

Comment: On a side note and speaking from my own experience, usually the go to when creating a WinForms app on PowerShell is to leave the PS Host for debugging purposes but when the app is finished you want to hide it.

Comment: Don't have multiple forms using `.topmost` in the same script. And yes, usually you;d hide the host window when presenting forms. If you want logging/info create a space on your form for it.

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah, I've referenced it from a different project than I thought I had for that particular method. RE: The problem being intermittent, I noticed the use of inconsistency in the question, I tried a few different things and couldn't and still can't reproduce. The purpose of me saying I can't reproduce is sometimes you don't get the full story immediately. I like to believe there isn't such thing as an intermittent problem in computing, we just haven't diagnosed it well enough yet. [_grin-thing_]

Comment: To address a lot of this: I was following the MS Docs for this, and it's weird they recommend Topmost when it doesn't work. @scepticalist mentions not using multiple forms with `.topmost`: is this still true if there's only ever one active at a time? @santiago squarzon this is more of a small script for technicians, I'd really like to have the Host up or at least a possibility of viewing it. @Ash as far as reproducing all I've needed to do is put about 6 forms in the same script and run through them in order.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon FYI Changing that line makes the forms no longer load. They just fail quietly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of forcing the form to be topmost is to open it with a new temporary form that is TopMost as parameter for `ShowDialog()`.

First, from your code remove the lines `$form.Topmost = $true` and `$form.TopLevel = $true`

Next, show your form like this:

```
# force the dialog TopMost by creating a temporary parent window for this form
$result = $form.ShowDialog((New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{TopMost = $true }))
```

---

Another way of doing this is to use a piece of C# to return a windowhandle which implements the [IWin32Window interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.iwin32window).
Then use this handle as the owner window for this form in the `.ShowDialog()` method of the form.

For this method, also remove the lines `$form.Topmost = $true` and `$form.TopLevel = $true` from your original code.

```
$iWin32Code = @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Win32Window : IWin32Window {
    public Win32Window(IntPtr handle) {
        Handle = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }
}
"@

if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'Win32Window').Type) {
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $iWin32Code -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms.dll 
}
```

Now, using that code, create a handle for the currently running PowerShell process

```
# get the owner handle from this PowerShell process
$ownerHandle = New-Object Win32Window -ArgumentList ([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
# and use that in the ShowDialog method as argument
$result = $form.ShowDialog($ownerHandle)
```

P.S. do not forget to clear your form from memory after you are done with it by calling

```
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: I tried the first part of your answer here and the first form goes directly behind the PS window still. I haven't tried the second yet, as with a half dozen forms that blows out my script length to almost double size and complexity which I'm not crazy about.

Comment: @GBarron Well... it's only 16 lines including the empty lines I put in there for readability. The C# code is only needed once in the script and can be reused for every form you show. Not really a blow-out I would think. P.S. What is your _"Powershell window"_ ? PowerShell console? ISE? VSCode?

Comment: sorry it's going to be Powershell console in production, for testing it's ISE.

Comment: @GBarron Ah, thanks. On my system, both options work both from console as well as from the ISE.. The second one (with the C# code) should definitively do what you need as it [Shows the form as a modal dialog box with the specified owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog_System_Windows_Forms_IWin32Window_). Please try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, however, I did not read the result of $form.ShowDialog() directly in the variable, rather I used variables that were updated by form controls.

Moving this line AFTER the ShowDialog() fixed the issue for me:

```
[void] $Form.ShowDialog() 
$form.TopMost = $true
```

Now the forms shows up in front.